# How to capture a part of a screen using Ruby on Windows?

Tags: ruby, winapi, screen-scraping

Instead of using some third party app, I'd like to write an app in Ruby that when invoked, will capture the full screen and save it in   c:\screenshot\snap000001.png

The graphic package is readily there, but how can you capture a region from the full screen so as to save it?

This program is to be invoked by some hot-key, such as setting it to be running when CTRL-PrtScn is pressed, or CTRL-CTRL (both control on left and right), or ALT-ALT.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't tried it (I'm not on windows). But you could use [Win32::Screenshot](http://rubyforge.org/projects/win32screenshot/).

While looking around, I've found [the following](http://flexonrails.net/?p=68), which does the screenshot using that library

```
width, height, bitmap = Win32::Screenshot.desktop
img_lst = ImageList.new
img_lst.from_blob(bitmap)
img_lst.write('public/screen.png')
```

And should write your screenshot as a png file.

Comment: Currently this gem fails on `write` under Ruby 1.9, but `.bitmap` outputs bmp-string-source nicely.

Comment: NB that this code snippet also requires the rmagick gem, I believe.