# How do I capture the screen using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, winapi

I need to capture the screen using Ruby, and then get an array of RGB pixel values for each pixel on the screen.

I tried the Windows API, and can bitblt the screen and retrieve the handle of the bitmap, but I have no idea how to access the raw RGB values within this handle's data.

This is what I have at the moment, and it's fast enough, but I need to get the RGB values from the hbitmap into an array that I can work with.

Anything as fast as Bitblt but easier would be appreciated too.

```
def getscreen()

width = Win32API.new("User32.dll","GetSystemMetrics",["L"],"L").call(0)
height = Win32API.new("User32.dll","GetSystemMetrics",["L"],"L").call(1)

#Get desktop DC, create a compatible dc, create a comaptible bitmap and select into compatible dc.
hddc = Win32API.new("User32.dll","GetDC",["L"],"L").call(Win32API.new("User32.dll","GetDesktopWindow",[],"L").call)
hcdc = Win32API.new("Gdi32.dll","CreateCompatibleDC",["L"],"L").call(hddc)
hbitmap = Win32API.new("Gdi32.dll","CreateCompatibleBitmap",["L","L","L"],"L").call(hddc,width,height)
Win32API.new("Gdi32.dll","SelectObject",["L","L"],"L").call(hcdc,hbitmap)
Win32API.new("Gdi32.dll","BitBlt",["L","L","L","L","L","L","L","L","P"],"L").call(hcdc,0,0,width,height,hddc,0,0,"SRCCOPY|CAPTUREBLT")

#save hbitmap to stream of byte as you mentioned
puts hbitmap


#

Win32API.new("User32.dll","ReleaseDC",["L","L"],"L").call(Win32API.new("User32.dll","GetDesktopWindow",[],"L").call,hddc)
Win32API.new("Gdi32.dll","DeleteDC",["L"],"L").call(hcdc)
Win32API.new("Gdi32.dll","DeleteObject",["L"],"L").call(hbitmap)

#Print screen width and height
puts "Screen width: #{width}"
puts "Screen height: #{height}"

end
```

Comment: hey, did not know ruby was shipped with win32API. not exactly a solution, but this might help : http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/166943

Comment: oh and this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678890/how-to-capture-a-part-of-a-screen-using-ruby-on-windows

Comment: I have tried the stackflow link above, can't get it to complie for me on 1.9.3

Comment: Yeah , I had a look at the 1st link above there, It seems a bit complicated and I though something simpler could be done via ruby or via the windows API (through Win32Api.new)

Comment: I looked again at the stackover flow link and I don't think I could get the rgb values from it

Comment: What is the reason for doing this?  I ask because I'm specifically interested in whether or not you're trying to save a screenshot of a webpage, in which case you can use phantomjs.

Comment: Anyone got any idea? I should be able to access the bitmap from the handle that I recieve within ruby, but I don't know how to, any help please? Its urgent :)

Comment: d11wtq,  I need to take the full screen and apply probabilisitc AI to it, so the ruby AI engine can learn from the screen, as such I preferably need an array with the full screen information within it so I can perform analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this so I though I would post the solution for others who may need help.

The GetDIBits Win32API function can be used to access the RGB array stored in the bitmap captured using the above code.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144879%28v=vs.85%29.aspx